# OpenBSD 6.5 /etc/mail/aliases correct format?

Tags: email, openbsd, aliases, smtpd

What is the correct entry format for an alias?

Right now I have

```
root:  xxxx@somewebsite.com
```

Running `newaliases -f /etc/mail/aliases` yields a syntax error. Are there examples in the manual page for aliases?

Answer (score 1):

Your alias file format is correct but you are using the wrong file with the -f option, that's why its giving an error.  See the relevant man page here:

https://man.openbsd.org/newaliases

```
-f file
    Use file as the configuration file, instead of the default /etc/mail/smtpd.conf.
```

As you can see there, -f option is to use a configuartion file other than the default one and not the alias file itself.

You can just run `newaliases` without any parameter and it should work.